# Doctrine 2 association inheritance with different classes

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine, doctrine-orm, associations

I'm using Doctrine 2 and single table inheritance, my topmost entity hierarchy is:

```
JS_File --> [one to many] --> JS_File_Version
```

And then my sub-class entity hierarchy is:

```
JS_Image (extends JS_File) --> [one to many] --> JS_Image_Version (extends JS_File_Version)
```

The inheritance mapping works perfectly for JS_File and JS_Image, and the association mapping works perfectly for JS_File --> JS_File_Version. But, when it comes to map the "versions" association on JS_Image I get:

```
'Property "versions" in "JS_Image" was already declared, but it must be declared only once'
```

I understand why this is, the association is being inherited from JS_File and I can't overwrite it, but how do I achieve what I'm trying to do? Basically, with inheritance, how can I tell Doctrine to use a different `targetEntity` for the sub-classes association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what I'm trying to do isn't possible (having both JS_File and JS_Image as concrete entities). I've followed the advice of someone from the doctrine-user mailing list instead:

> The way I solved this was to use an abstract base class and then define the actual mappings on the subclasses. For example, you could do something like:
>
> JS_AbstractFile with subclasses: JS_File and JS_Image
>   JS_AbstractVersion with subclasses: JS_FileVersion and JS_ImageVersion
>
> AbstractFile and AbstractVersion can define the property (and getter/setters) but you shouldn't define any mapping information for the field. Then in your subclass you re-define the property along with mapping information (at least, thats how I did it since I used annotations)

http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/msg/243f355191d3a512

Answer (score 2):

maybe what you are looking for is the [@MappedSuperclass](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) annotation on your JS_Image entity.

I think i used it some time ago, but according to the docs it allows you to *"define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes"*, and it can also *"appear in the middle of an otherwise mapped inheritance hierarchy"*.

Maybe you can use this to tell Doctrine to see your JS_Image entity as the actual "parent" entity for your subentities. don't have time to test this now though, so please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it looks like what I was trying to do isn't possible. I've decided on a different approach (see other answer) which I think is similar to this.